# SP2016: How can I add visit counter for documents?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, ajax

My SharePoint site has anonymous access and extended for internet. I want to stroe anonymous number of visits for each document (such as Images, Videos, and etc.) and show to all anonymous visitors.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable usage cookies to generate unique user IDs so SharePoint can record the usage events from anonymous access.

Please refer to：[Use recommendations and popular items on websites with anonymous users in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/use-recommendations-and-popular-items-on-websites-with-anonymous-users)